# Add original location of refiled entries to LOGBOOK after org-refile

Tags: org-mode

With this setup `(setq org-log-refile 'time)` I have the following notes added to my TODO entry that I refiled (already twice and it is ended up in long someday-maybe):

```
* TASK Note on where the entry was refiled from
:LOGBOOK:  
- Refiled on [2016-04-04 Mon 00:57]
- Refiled on [2015-05-15 Fri 13:53]
- State "TASK"       from ""           [2015-05-15 Fri 13:53]
:END:
```

What I would also like to have is the note about the place where it was refiled from. Like so:

```
* TASK Note on where the entry was refiled from
:LOGBOOK:  
- Refiled on [2016-04-04 Mon 00:57] from ~/emacs-tasks.org::*Tasks%20workflow
- Refiled on [2015-05-15 Fri 13:53] from ~/stuff.org
- State "TASK"       from ""           [2015-05-15 Fri 13:53]
:END:
```

The problem is that the templates for adding notes `org-log-note-headings` do not support a proper placeholder (something like `%F` used in `org-capture-templates`). Moreover, it is explicitly not recommended to change these templates. Any suggestions how to achieve desired result?

Comment: Posted a feature request on emacs-orgmode@gnu.org

Comment: Here are relevant questions about leaving links at the source location of refiled entry - https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/47011/org-refile-and-leave-a-link-behind and https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/36861/org-refile-leave-a-link-to-refiled-item

Comment: would you mind sharing a link to your feature requests, so as to second it? I'd really like to see this kind of backlinks.

Comment: Thank you @aguadopd Original feature request is here - https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-orgmode/2018-09/msg00116.html

Answer (score 1):

For now I came up with the following work around:

```lisp
;; do not use default refile logging
(setq org-log-refile nil)

;; add custom logging instead
(add-hook 'org-after-refile-insert-hook #'clavis-org-refile-add-refiled-from-note)

(advice-add 'org-refile
            :before
            #'clavis-org-save-source-id-and-header)

(defvar clavis-org-refile-refiled-from-id nil)
(defvar clavis-org-refile-refiled-from-header nil)

(defun clavis-org-save-source-id-and-header ()
  "Saves refile's source entry's id and header name to `clavis-org-refile-refiled-from-id' and `clavis-org-refile-refiled-from-header'. If refiling entry is first level entry then it stores file path and buffer name respectively."
  (interactive)
  (save-excursion
    (if (org-up-heading-safe)
        (progn
          (setq clavis-org-refile-refiled-from-id (org-id-get nil t))
          (setq clavis-org-refile-refiled-from-header
                (org-get-heading 'no-tags 'no-todo 'no-priority 'no-comment)))
      (setq clavis-org-refile-refiled-from-id (buffer-file-name))
      (setq clavis-org-refile-refiled-from-header (buffer-name)))))

(defun clavis-org-refile-add-refiled-from-note ()
  "Adds a note to entry at point on where the entry was refiled from using the org ID from `clavis-org-refile-refiled-from-id' and `clavis-org-refile-refiled-from-header' variables."
  (interactive)
  (when (and clavis-org-refile-refiled-from-id
             clavis-org-refile-refiled-from-header)
    (save-excursion
      (let* ((note-format "- Refiled on [%s] from [[id:%s][%s]]\n")
             (time-format (substring (cdr org-time-stamp-formats) 1 -1))
             (time-stamp (format-time-string time-format (current-time))))
        (goto-char (org-log-beginning t))
        (insert (format note-format
                        time-stamp
                        clavis-org-refile-refiled-from-id
                        clavis-org-refile-refiled-from-header))))
    (setq clavis-org-refile-refiled-from-id nil)
    (setq clavis-org-refile-refiled-from-header nil)))
```

Comment: What an elegant solution! I love it!

Comment: Very nice. Unfortunately, when refiling many tasks at once with a region, it only adds a log entry for the first one. Also, this is missing changing the "id:" for "file:" when the link ends up being file-path rather than an id.