# org-refile: leave a link to refiled item

Tags: org-mode, logging

My workflow: everyday, I capture (using a template) a journal entry that get saved to a datetree journal.org file.

From there I would like to refile to different "project" files but I would like to keep a trace and a link in my journal.org file.
To illustrate; my journal.org would look like this BEFORE the refile:

```
* 2017
** 2017-11 November
*** 2017-11-13 Monday
**** My entry
***** a heading
****** TODO some task
```

and like this AFTER the refile:

```
* 2017
** 2017-11 November
*** 2017-11-13 Monday
**** My entry
***** a heading
****** REFILLED some task
:LOGBOOK:
Refiled on [2017-11-13 Mon] to ~/emacs-tasks.org::*Tasks%20workflow
:END:
```

What would I do to achieve this? TIA

Comment: Here's a newer [thread](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/47011/org-refile-and-leave-a-link-behind) addressing the topic.

Comment: Somewhat related [org-super-links](https://github.com/toshism/org-super-links)