# Org : refile and leave a link behind

Tags: org-mode

I would like to "augment" the `org-refile` function in such a way that, once I moved the heading from the source to the destination, a link to this last file is created and inserted in the source, in place of the pre-existing heading.
The source will generally be a `TODO` item, but in case of a tree, the title of the link should be the top-level heading of course.

I'm new to `elisp` and don't know much about `emacs` customization either, so any hint or help towards a solution would be greatly appreciated.
(I'll also try to find my way as soon as I get a minute to work on it, of course).

Answer (score 4):

Here's a lightly tested walkthrough of how you could get started with
this.

The first thing we need is a way to capture where the
heading-to-be-refiled is.  Org might store this information itself,
but we don't need to worry about that.  Let's create a variable that
stores a marker to the location (see `(info "(elisp)Markers")`) and
then use advice (`(info "(elisp)Advising Functions")`) to instruct
`org-refile` to set the variable to that marker before refiling.

```
(defvar my/org-last-refile-marker nil)

(advice-add 'org-refile
            :before
            (lambda (&rest _)
              (save-excursion
                (org-back-to-heading)
                (setq my/org-last-refile-marker (point-marker))))
            '((name . "my/org-set-refile-marker")))
```

Next we need to store a link after the heading has been refiled.  Org
provides a hook, `org-after-refile-insert-hook`, that we can use.

```
(defvar my/org-last-refile-link nil)

(defun my/org-set-last-refile-link ()
  (setq my/org-last-refile-link (org-store-link nil)))

(add-hook 'org-after-refile-insert-hook #'my/org-set-last-refile-link)
```

Now the link text for that heading will be stored in the variable
`my/org-last-refile-link`.  The remaining piece is to go back to the
original location and insert the link.  Again, we can advise
`org-refile`, this time to do something *after* instead of *before*.

```
(advice-add 'org-refile
            :after
            (lambda (&rest _)
              (when (and my/org-last-refile-marker
                         my/org-last-refile-link)
                (let ((buf (marker-buffer my/org-last-refile-marker)))
                  (when (buffer-live-p buf)
                    (with-current-buffer buf
                      (save-excursion
                        (goto-char my/org-last-refile-marker)
                        (insert (concat my/org-last-refile-link "\n"))))))
                (setq my/org-last-refile-marker nil)
                (setq my/org-last-refile-link nil)))
            '((name . "my/org-insert-refile-marker")))
```

That's got at least a few rough edges.  For example, `org-refile`
accepts a prefix argument that makes it do something other than refile.
Also it might not work when called via `org-agenda-refile`.  Another
thing to consider is whether you want this behavior for every
`org-refile` call.  If not, it might make sense to make a custom
command that wraps `org-refile` instead of using the `:before` advice
above.

But hopefully above gives you something to build off of.

Answer (score 1):

If you're willing to use org ids to create links that don't depend on the location of the heading, then the problem becomes a little bit easier to solve because the whole link creation process can be done before anything is refiled. You can use ids for org links by setting the variable `org-id-link-to-org-use-id` to true.

**Important note:** this will not work as intended when refiling a region containing more than one subtree or if you use any prefixes on the refile command.

So the function and advice setup is done like so:

```
(defun org-refile--insert-link ( &rest _ )
  (org-back-to-heading)
  (let* ((refile-region-marker (point-marker))
         (source-link (org-store-link nil)))
    (org-insert-heading)
    (insert source-link)
    (goto-char refile-region-marker)))

(advice-add 'org-refile
            :before
            #'org-refile--insert-link))
```

The first function moves the pointer to the beginning of the heading. We save the marker at that point, and also store the link at that point. Insert a new heading (depending on your settings this might need to explicitly be `org-insert-heading-after-current`) and insert the link we saved. Finally we move the pointer back to our saved marker so that org-refile starts with the pointer where it is expected.

Comment: This is nice! Works like charm. Thanks.